# How to prove the sum of the reciprocals of the product of natural numbers with their increments?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

How can I prove the following expression?

$$ \sum_{n=x}^{m} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{m+1} $$

Thanks in advance if anyone is able to help me!

Comment: **Hint :** $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)} =\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$=$\dfrac{(n+1)-n}{n(n+1)}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescope

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: Ah thank you all very much, I had guessed before that it would be some kind of telescoping series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that (by partial fractions) we have $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
and thus $$ \sum_{n=x}^{m} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} =\sum_{n=x}^{m}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$$
$$=\big(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}\big)+\big(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+2}\big)+...+\big(\frac{1}{m-1}-\frac{1}{m}\big)+\big(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}\big)$$
$$=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{m+1}$$
since all the terms in the middle cancel each other.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! :-)